# Ionic App - Cordova inApp Browser

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created an ionic android app that reads data from the database. One of the fields in the database is the website url. I'm doing data binding where I can display the url using:

{{accommodation.website}}

. I want to be able to use this to display an external web page. Unfortunately this is not working using this code:

```
 <a ng-href="#" target="_self" onclick="window.open('{{accommodation.website}}','_self','location=yes')" class="button button-positive">Website</a><p>{{accommodation.website}}</p>
```

and as a result it displays :

```
http://localhost:8100/%7B%7Baccommodation.website%7D%7D
Cannot GET /%7B%7Baccommodation.website%7D%7D
```

But when I use:

```
 <a ng-href="#" target="_self" onclick="window.open('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-href.asp','_self','location=yes')" class="button button-positive">Website</a><p>{{accommodation.website}}</p>
```

It works fine on android phone. Instead of hard coding the url, I want to use data binding as I am working with ion-list. I spent all day trying to fix this. Please help.

Comment: Have you installed inappbrowser plugin in your ionic-framework

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you, for detail, go to [Nic's Blog](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/), and check out comments. Regards!

```
<a ng-href="{{accommodation.website}}" target="_self" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_self','location=yes')" class="button button-positive">Website</a><p>{{accommodation.website}}</p>
```

Comment: @JamesNgondo  I am glad that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, use `ng-click`, not `onclick`, but that is beside the point since you should just be using `ng-href="{{accommodation.website}}"`